# abap cds --> calculate average on currency field with currency_conversion

Tags: abap, cds

I'm trying to calculate the average of a currency field in abap cds per faktura.

Since @DefaultAggregation: #AVG is not working, I've figured out another way to do this using this guide:
[Calculate Average in Analytics Engine](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/02/04/calculate-average-in-analytics-engine-core-data-services-analysis-for-office/)

This is a quite simple workaround:

```
//Main field which is to be averaged is been default aggregated as sum
  @DefaultAggregation: #SUM
  NetDaysGranted,

//Count field sum as aggregation
 @DefaultAggregation: #SUM
 1              as Count,
```

by counting the "positions" and use `@AnalyticsDetails.query.formula` one layer above to div the amount by the amount of positions.

```
@AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #COLUMNS
@EndUserText.label: 'Net Arrears Days'
@DefaultAggregation: #FORMULA
@AnalyticsDetails.query.formula :'NetDaysGranted / Count'
1            as  NetDaysGranted,
```

This works perfectly fine.

The only problem I have, is that in my case this is a currency field and I need to display the average in display currency.

the cds function `currency_conversion` however does not let me use the `'1'`. It throws following error:

*Function CURRENCY_CONVERSION: For parameter AMOUNT only Columns,Paths,Parameters can be passed*

Is there a possibility to use currency_conversion on a calculated field?